# Subtract if number is negative, add if number is positive

Tags: c#, math

I want to remove 10 from `Vector3 diff` `x` & `z` if is is `< 0`, and add 10 if it is `>= 0`. Is there a better way to do that?

```
            if (diff.x < 0)
                diff.x -= 10;
            else if (diff.x >= 0)
                diff.x += 10;
            if (diff.z < 0)
                diff.z -= 10;
            else if (diff.z >= 0)
                diff.z += 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the conditional operator to only make a single comparison for both x and z. Again, people can have many different opinions about conciseness, readability, etc.

```cs
diff.x += (diff.x < 0 ? -10 : 10);
diff.z += (diff.z < 0 ? -10 : 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are doubles, you could use Math.CopySign. Math.CopySign(x,y) has the magnitude of x and the sign of y.

```
diff.x += Math.CopySign( 10, diff.x);
diff.z += Math.CopySign( 10, diff.z);
```